# css3 selector, nth child incrementing by 1

Tags: css, css-selectors

i am using css3 selector to select different childs . is their any alternative instead of hardcoding it

```
.checkout_main .check_tr th:nth-child(1){
    width:50px;padding-left:10px;
}
.check_tr th:nth-child(2){
    width:300px;padding-left:10px;
}
.check_tr th:nth-child(3){
    width:50px;padding-left:10px;
}
.check_tr th:nth-child(4){
    width:100px;padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: if it is only four childs and different styles for each then no need to worry about it.

Comment: Do you have a specific pattern (like 1, 3, 5th elements have setting etc)? Reason is because your 2nd and 4th doesn't seem to be the same while 1 and 3 are.

Comment: nth child property are mainly for pattern elements ?

Comment: @Dhruv: It is not only for pattern elements. But if you wish to minmize repetitions then there should be a pattern to it because you cannot combine settings of children who don't have same settings.

Comment: ok .. i did it .. applied odd and numbering .. as even ones have diff properties ..

Comment: @Dhruv: By the way, one extra suggestion. Your `padding-left` seems to be a common setting, so just set that once on the `th`. That will minimize repetitions too :)

Comment: also is their a way to multiply that nth number with width? @Harry

Comment: @Dhruv: Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr95N/) on how to combine.

Comment: did that only... thnx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two alternatives

```
You can use odd even
:nth-child(odd)
{
  width: 100px;
}

:nth-child(even)
{
  width:200px; 
}
```

Another way is you have to formulate an+b . Then it works, Let me know your html. Ii ll try and tell you an+b form.

Comment: The alternative children don't seems to have the same properties.

Comment: <tr class="check_tr">
   <th >S.No.</th>
   <th>Item Name</th>
   <th style="">Quantity</th>
   <th style="">Price</th>
  </tr>

Comment: Yeah:) His question says alternative way, so i posted two ways.his structure is dif. so i asked for html structure

Comment: ur way is better .. i used it .. cant tick it as ans for another 7 mins .. since even child have diff prop so only using on odd ones

Comment: also is their a way to multiply that nth number with width? @user3168736

Comment: I guess you need javascript or jquery. But it's not possible with css csse